# Can Visual Studio Express run from USB drive?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-express, usb-drive

Using an arbitrary Windows machine (2000/XP or later), I can

1. install Eclipse CDT to a USB drive
2. move that USB drive onto a different
   Windows machine--one that does not
   have any form of Eclipse software
   already installed, and potentially a different version of Windows (but 2000/XP or later)
3. use Eclipse to develop application-level C/C++ programs on that second machine (and that includes using the debugger), running directly from the USB drive without copying anything to C:.

I can do all this *without* having Administrator privileges on *either* machine.

I can do the same with NetBeans, and with several other IDEs that support C/C++ development.

Is it possible to do this with any version of Visual Studio Express?

If not, can you explain the technical reason(s) this doesn't work?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931133/can-i-run-visual-studio-2010-from-a-flash-drive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse is apparently designed to be what Microsoft calls an [XCOPY deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment)...meaning that it doesn't require any special entries in the Windows Registry (or any other "installation identity" on the target machine) in order to work properly.

Visual Studio is most decidedly *not* designed like this.  It makes *extensive* modifications to the registry during installation, and those entries (and any other resources like special folder locations) will be missing on any other computer.

So you might be able to install Visual Studio on a thumb drive, but some artifacts of the installation will be put on the C: drive, and you will only be able to use the thumb drive with that machine.

Comment: Thanks. But when you say "the registry", are you referring to HKLM or some other section that requires Administrator privileges?

Comment: +1 Correct unless you want to use something like Thinstall. With that, it should be possible, but may not be terribly fast. Visual Studio uses a lot of registry entries, associations and does install quite a few shared components into Program Files. Unless you're able to capture all of those and include them (which is what Thinstall does), it's not really feasible to create a portable VS.

Comment: And just to be sure, are you including "Visual Studio Express" when you refer to "Visual Studio"?

Comment: Yes, VS Express follows similar installation principles.

Comment: @peachy - Thanks for the pointer to Thinstall! Put it in a separate answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: Thinstall does not work very well in practice, I would avoid it in any environment you'd like to "rely on".

Comment: Is it possible to download Visual Studio 2015 to the flash drive and install it on a computer with no internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could install VS Express in a VM running from the USB drive using Portable VirtualBox or VMPlayer. Not the best performance but its usable for not too big projects or learning.

Answer (score 1):

It can definitely be done! I've seen a technician with a copy of it on a USB stick. the only visible flaw was that when you run on a different PC it requires you to enter the license. I could not see any other problems (speed/debugger etc. it all worked on his copy).
check this out:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/appvirtualization/dd334515.aspx
 I believe the virtualized package I saw was made by this means:
http://spoon.net/Studio/
Unfortunately it would be matter of experimenting with it...

No VM or extra software was needed!