# VS 2010 on a flash drive using Vbox portable?

Tags: c#, virtualbox

Ive seen :

[Can Visual Studio Express run from USB drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877290/can-visual-studio-express-run-from-usb-drive/4247854#4247854)

after seeking if I could run VS 2010 in a flash drive. has someone actually succeeded in trying such?

Where Im being taught only have VS Express ( Im into C# ) and its a real PITA as I also need to use some plugins which become handy.

If someone has succeeded, how much space could VS 2010 ( C#) plus Virtual box possibly need ( guesstimates are fine ofc)?

thx

Answer (score 2):

In general principle, yes, you can run pretty much any app from a VM anywhere. VBox portable, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't cripple the VM concept so as to make that impossible.

You can run Visual Studio within a VM typically without any problems, so you should be able to set up and run this just fine. Might want to check the EULA and see if it has any mention of such a thing, though.

The real issue you will run into is flash drive speeds. VS does a good bit of reading during use, and a VM will only make that worse (by having the virtual HDD on the flash drive). Over USB 2.0, you'll run into some serious slow-down. USB 3 or eSATA may work better, if you can get a fast flash drive/external disk drive to use.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done that, but I'm using non-portable VirtualBox a lot, which practically never gave me a headache, even with some very complex software installed in the VM.

From that experience, I'd say Windows 7 comes at roughly 7GB, but it might grow a bit over time. A full VS 2010 Ultimate takes up a bit more than 6 GB, so you'll end up at 13.

Of course, you can simply install C# only and leave VB, F#, and C++ out of it, saving you up to 4GB. However, I think you'd still have to go for a 16GB stick, otherwise the hard disk of your VM will appear to be full which leads to a plethora of problems.