# How to make VS portable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ide, codeblocks

I did some reading on IDE`s (I am currently using Code::Blocks) and everyone appears to think that VS is the best IDE but I am wondering if I can make it portable. For example installing it on a USB and have it work on a computer that has never had it installed before.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio can be installed in an USB drive: It has a lot of headers, tools and runtimes to be installed, and IIRC it needs the change the system PATH, and even if you ask for it to be installed in D:, it will install files in C: too. As for VS being the best IDE, you should try it before assuming this... (Note that I *do* believe it's the best IDE, but then, I worked with VS since VS6 through VS2010, and no other IDE I tried, like Anjunta, QT Creator or even the excellent Code::Blocks, was as good IMHO)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio Express run from USB drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877290/can-visual-studio-express-run-from-usb-drive)

Comment: i dont understand why this question is -1 :|, and paercebal i have tried VS before the only reason why i stoped using it was because of some errors and poor support i got when i was using vs C# i contemplating going back to it after reading several threads that said it was the best ide.

Comment: @I Phantasm I: I did not downvote, never do, but on a side note the Q is exact duplicate of the link I added.

Comment: ahh okay..sorry :( thats probably the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick version: No.

VS is a huge application, it integrates with Windows at a low level in places: it is a native debugger. Additionally much of VS is built on COM, which requires registration.

Comment: thank you for the answer i suspected this but i wonted to make sure as it would be great if i could make it portable. ahh well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific set of computers that you are going to work on, you can install virtualization software in all of them once, and run VS inside a Virtual Machine. The virtual machine can be created and run directly from an external USB Hard Drive.

I have done this with both VMWare Workstation and the free VMware Player. The performance penalty of running the VM from an USB is not much and the portability of your environment is great.