# Can I run Visual Studio 2010 from a flash drive?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

At my work I have a new machine with windows 7. I want to keep up my development skills so I wanted to load my copy of Visual Studio 2010 on the machine but I don't have admin rights.

I have a 16 gig flash drive. Is it possible to load it on there and run it from the flash drive? So far, just double clicking the setup icon gives me the admin credential pop up.

It won't let me change where  Visual Studio should be loaded.

Comment: By ".NET 2010" do you mean "Visual Studio 2010"? .NET and Visual Studio are somewhat different...

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877290/can-visual-studio-express-run-from-usb-drive

Comment: yes, sorry...Visual Studio 2010

Comment: You can make a symlink for the directory and point it to the flash drive after installing Visual Studio, but you will not be able run it elsewhere/another PC 'portably'.

Answer (score 3):

No. Visual Studio is very integrated with the environment.

Answer (score 3):

Although Visual Studio is nowhere near portable, not from a technical  point of view, nor from a licensing point of view, you can always try virtualization solutions.
One that comes to mind is [Ceedo (Personal)](http://www.ceedo.com/products/ceedo-personal.html).

Comment: Virtual PC which is free with Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called SharpDevelop that is like Visual Studio and it can be portable

[Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx)

This will tell you how to make a portal able version

[Sharp Develop on USB](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/laputa/archive/2008/08/16/sharpdevelop-on-a-memory-stick.aspx)

there is also [Snippit Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)

With both options there is no cost or licensing issues

Answer (score 0):

One option is [portable VirtualBox](http://vbox.me). It probably won't be smooth though.