# How to install Visual Studio Express 2013 on ONLY an external Hard Drive (not on C at all)?

Tags: visual-studio, filesystems, installation, location

I currently do not have my laptop and don't know how long it will be until I get it back.  I have an external hard drive and access to university computers, but they don't let us install programs on the computer, so I can't use Visual Studio off the machines.  Only my external.  I know I can install *SOME* of the files on the external, but it still wants to install ~2.5gigs on C:

Is there any way to install the whole thing on the external, or perhaps use a friend's computer to install it, then move all the files it puts in C: onto the external?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Mostly because of the OS dependencies that exist like .NET 4.5, IE10. And not to mention SQL Server Local DB which gets installed too.

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Can Visual Studio Express run from USB drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877290/can-visual-studio-express-run-from-usb-drive)

So in short, the answer is no.
In long, it would be possible to create a virtual machine with VMWare or similar, and put that machine image on the external drive, then install Visual Studio Express on there ...